# react-hook-form custom uncontrolled inputs don't update their meta state (dirty, touched)

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

EDIT: solved by a react-hook-form module update.

**Problem**

react-hook-form does not update form input state `dirty`, `touched` on custom components where `name` is dynamically passed to `register`. Specifically, field array inputs where the `name` is something like `ingredients.0.description` will track the input value but not the input state. Simple names like `question` or `name` seem to behave correctly.

Reproduction of the bug on this [CodeSandbox.io environment](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-star-c2e49?file=/src/App.tsx).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type or change the value in the "name" field (on the first line)
2. Type or change the value in any of the "description" fields (the field array)
3. Open react-hook-form DevTools (the pink icon in the bottom right of the browser)
4. See that the `ingredients` fields did not update `dirty` or `touched` values despite not matching `defaultValue` and having blurred off the input
5. See that the `name` field shows `dirty: true, touched: true` correctly

**Context**

I'm using react-hook-form and running into problems when integrating it with a custom uncontrolled component.

In most (all?) of the examples I see, the `register` function is either applied to a native HTML Input Element as one or the other:

```js
<input {...register("field_name")} />
```

```js
<input ref={register} name="field_name" />
```

Because I have some custom input styling, I'd like to make reusable components that integrate into react-hook-form, and though I could do something like:

```js
// Input.tsx
export function Input(props) {
type Props = {
  type: string;
  name: string;
};

export function Input(props: Props) {
  const { type, name } = props;
  const { register, getValues, formState } = useFormContext();
  return <input type={type} {...register(name)} />;
}


// App.tsx
<FormProvider {...methods} >
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Input name="field_name" type="text" />
  </form>
<FormProvider/>
```

**Questions**

1. Am I using `register` incorrectly?
2. Can `register` take a name dynamically or must it be a static string? Is my field array name description malformed?
3. Do uncontrolled component methods need to be applied directly to an `<input />` or is it possible to wrap with a custom component and pass the props? What's the most idiomatic way to do this with react-hook-form?
4. How can I modify the code in my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-star-c2e49?file=/src/App.tsx) to correctly reflect all field inputs' states?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @quielfaulo this was actually resolved by a version update